Does Salacious B. Crumb have a tail longer than his body?
I'm making a custom Jabba's Palace diorama with 3.75-inch action figurines. I've noticed that most of the Salacious figures on the market have relatively short tails. Given that I recall Salacious' tail being long enough, possibly longer than his body, I've been looking for an official reference to that physiological characteristic, but I can only find incomplete pictures of Salacious' tail. Watching Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi (1983) isn't particularly helpful. Scarce images of the original puppet also reveal too little. Even the Kowakian monkey-lizard from the TV series The Mandalorian has rather short tails.
An affirmative response to my question raises the possibility of whether Salacious was influenced by the squirrel monkey (genus Saimiri); the only genus with a tail longer than its body and with resemblance (dark nose and mouth) to Jabba's jester.
Detail of a picture by Taryn Simon that shows Salacious at The Lucasfilm archives at Lucas's Skywalker Ranch in Marin Country, California. (2007)

EDIT:
I just have discovered a short film about Salacious that includes an interview with Phil Tippett regarding the origins of the Salacious name. The featurette is from Star Wars Complete Saga (2011), a nine-disc Blu-ray collection. In the short clip, the original puppet is shown sitting and rotating 360 degrees on a small screen, with a very long tail. I don't have the disk, but the tail appears to be longer than the one on Tony McVey's sculpture, which @alexg highlighted in his answer. By the way, Star Wars: Complete Saga is Canon.
Still image from Featurette film included in Star Wars Complete Saga Blu-ray (2011)

EDIT2:
I found the blog Star Wars Aficionado Website depicting a full size of Salacious B. Crumb while getting a detailed spray painting for skin texture. To me, it looks that the tale is near or longer than Salacious body. Now, I believe is about to do some graphic math with Salacious standing on his feet and the tail straightened to determine the approximate length of body and tail.


Going by the last photo you added, the tail must be longer than just the head & body, but definitely shorter than head + body + legs. Do this experiment: measure with your fingers, a piece of paper, anything, from the top of the head to the butt of Salacious. Then see how much of the tail this covers: a lot! It leaves out a tiny bit of tail that is definitely shorter than his legs. This comparison is valid because, fortunately for us, in this picture Salacious' body curvature matches that of his tail.

The image below is the rear of what's described as a "1:1 prop replica, hand-sculpted by Tony McVey, who sculpted the character for the original film", sold by Regal Robot. An interview with McVey emphasizes that the size and detail are meant to match the original prop with precision:

Tom Spina: [...] We got to spend many, many, many hours and days, actually, with [the original]. We were able to measure things. We were able to take photos and really provide Tony with a foundation to make sure that this new sculpt was going to be one-to-one, 100% the same size, the same look, etc. And, you know, we sent Tony a lot of reference photos.


StarWars.com: [...] And also, Tony, I am curious if now that he's in the spotlight and this is something that's going to be in people's homes, if you are tempted or added additional details that you would have liked to see on the original.
Tony McVey: Not really, because I knew Tom was going to look at this thing with the eagle eye and say, “Oh, you can't do that. That wasn't in the original, dude, you can't put that in there.” So, no, I just tried to stick to what was in the original piece. That seems about the safest route.


So the tail shown here ought to be the same dimensions as the original. The first link above shows some pictures from other angles as well. There are more views in a long unboxing video, which also includes a discussion on the tail posture (note: I haven't watched the whole video, just scanned forward to where they seemed to be talking about the tail; there may be other clues elsewhere). Tom Spina says there that the length of the tail was a challenge for the static model, and they chose to show it curled in this way so that it did not dominate the figure and prevent owners from displaying it in typical settings.
Because of the curl, it's a bit harder to judge the true length of the tail compared to the body, but I'd say that it's a little shorter than the entire body top-to-toe. That's mainly because the legs are actually very long, certainly in comparison to a real-world monkey. It's a close-run thing, though, and the tail is definitely longer than Crumb's combined head, neck and torso. Perhaps you can make a better guess on the basis of all the pictures, which I think should generally be a good supplement for images of the original prop.
